# How can I get the Physical Path property of a site

Tags: powershell, iis

When I just list the sites with the default formatting, it shows the physical path.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $sm = Get-IISServerManager

PS C:\Windows\system32> $sm.Sites

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Default Web Site 1    Started    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:                                                                                                                                                                                               
Test             2    Started    C:\inetpub\wwwroot_Test       http *:5007:                                                                                                                                                                                             



PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

But I can't find any corresponding property on the object.

```
$sm.Sites[0] | Format-List *



ApplicationDefaults        : Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationDefaults
Applications               : {Default Web Site/, ...}
Bindings                   : {http *:80:}
Id                         : 1
Limits                     : Microsoft.Web.Administration.SiteLimits
LogFile                    : Microsoft.Web.Administration.SiteLogFile
Name                       : Default Web Site
ServerAutoStart            : True
State                      : Started
TraceFailedRequestsLogging : Microsoft.Web.Administration.SiteTraceFailedRequestsLogging
VirtualDirectoryDefaults   : Microsoft.Web.Administration.VirtualDirectoryDefaults
Attributes                 : {name, id, serverAutoStart, state}
ChildElements              : {bindings, limits, logFile, traceFailedRequestsLogging...}
ElementTagName             : site
IsLocallyStored            : True
Methods                    : {Start, Stop}
RawAttributes              : {[name, Default Web Site], [id, 1], [serverAutoStart, True], [state, 1]}
Schema                     : Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

**Direct Question:** How can I get the physical path of a site?

**Indirect Question:** Is there a way to find how the object is formatted by default? Then I could look up the Physical Path from there.

Comment: Doesn't $sm.Sites[0]."Physical Path" work?

Comment: [The corresponding property name is `physicalPath`](https://serverfault.com/a/611724/105072)

Comment: For me, neither of these two work. Please note that the serverfault answer is for a different PS Module (WebAdministration).

Comment: You need to read the physical path of the root virtual directory of the root application of the site. Open `applicationHost.config` in Notepad and check the XML file for details.

Comment: Apparently ``$sm.Sites[0].Applications[0].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath`` works.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After decompiling and debugging this for a few hours, I found the expression powershell uses internally:

`$_.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath`

No idea how you are supposed to find that out without a decompiler.

Comment: Values in a listing which don't actually exist are produced by viewformats. In this case: : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/IISAdministration/1.1.0.0/Content/iiscommands.format.ps1xml

Answer (score 8):

```
$physicalPath = (Get-Website "Default Web Site" | Select-Object).PhysicalPath
```

Answer (score 4):

I have been using

```
Import-Module Webadministration

gci "IIS:\Sites\{target site name}"                                `
                    | Where-Object {$_.NodeType -eq 'application'} `
                    | Sort-Object -Property PhysicalPath, name
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfect for my needs.  Just remember to define `{target site name}` in your script as the specific site name, in case you are running multiple sites under IIS.

Thanks @ΩmegaMan for this little gem

Answer (score 1):

Unless re-created with custom config, Default website is always the first instance, so would go with this myself...

```
(Get-IISSite)[0].Applications.VirtualDirectories.PhysicalPath
```

Simples :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the physical path in this way:

```
echo (Get-WebApplication "Your application" | Select-Object).PhysicalPath
```

Answer (score 0):

### 2 websites on my test.

```
$x = Get-IISSite
$x[1].Applications.VirtualDirectories.PhysicalPath
```

### C:\inetpub\test

```
$x[0].Applications.VirtualDirectories.PhysicalPath
```

### %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot

Answer (score 0):

The website is the application the root, "/", path. For example, to get (and set) the physical path of the default web site:

```
$manager = Get-IISServerManager
$rootsite = $manager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"]
$rootsite.PhysicalPath = "C:\my\websites\path"
$manager.CommitChanges()
```