# How to get a website's physical path with IISAdministration alone?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to determine the physical path of an IIS website via Powershell. For unclear reasons, I cannot install/import WebAdministration so I am left with just IISAdministration. That, in turn, is extremely obtuse and I don't see an option via [Get-IISSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissite) to actually extract the physical path even though it gets printed when you run the cmdlet itself.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/q/52498299/45375 may have solutions. If so, we can close your question as a duplicate. The `Get-IISSite` docs aren't helpful; they list the output data type as `Object`(!) Unfortunately, the docs for many cmdlets are plagued by such lack of specificity.

Comment: @mklement0 It seems like that has just the answer I was looking for. I tried searching for an answer here before but of course could not find any despite trawling through several.